# Render a button after the child, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here I am mapping a component, which results in many project cards being rendered on the screen. I would like to render a plus button after the last child inside of the map. I am thinking of something such as :last-child selector in CSS but I need to be able to set onClick and other stuff to that button. I was thinking there might be other "react pure" way to solve this? Any ideas?

```
projectsByCompany[companyKey].map((project) => (
      <Project
        name={project.name}
        year={project.year}
        to={`${props.match.url}/${project.slug}`}
      />
    ))}
```

Comment: Can you not just render the button after the map function - why does it have to be inside the map?

Comment: I suppose if you need the button in the map for some reason, you can use the [second and third arg of the `map()` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) to test for the final array element.

Answer (score 0):

map functions second argument is the index of current element so you can render  button when i is pointing to the last element in the array

```
               projectsByCompany[companyKey].map((project,i) => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <Project
                                name={project.name}
                                year={project.year}
                                to={`${props.match.url}/${project.slug}`}
                            />
                            {i===projectsByCompany[companyKey].length-1&&<button>Add</button>}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ))
```

Comment: I don't think you have access to the calling array inside the callback; use [the third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) (the calling array) of the `map()` callback instead.

Comment: @zcoop98 you can do that, but you do have access to the calling array. Both approaches are valid although your suggestion works better for detaching the function from this render function.

Comment: Sweet! I stand corrected then. I didn't realize you had access to it in that context.